# a linha 9 e 20, estao dando erro, mas nao consigo achar o que o erro, as duas linhas mostram este erro [error] expression cannot be used as a function

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int resp, opc, dhcp, ftp, iot, opcdesa, ip, gate, dns, sn;

char nome[200], senha[200];

//João Luiz de Oliveira

main(){

    printf("Quer criar um servidor? 1-sim/2-nao\n");

    scanf("%d",&resp);

9   while((resp<1) (resp>2)){

        printf("Responda com 1-sim/2-nao\n");

        scanf("%d",&resp);

    }

    while(resp ==1 ){

        printf("Qual servidor?\n");

        printf("1-DHCP\n2-FTP\n3-IoT\n4-ver servidores ativados\n5-desativar um servidor\n");

            scanf("%d",&opc);

20      while((opc<1)(opc>5)){

        printf("Responda com: \n1-DHCP\n2-FTP\n3-IoT\n4-ver servidores 
ativados\n5-desativar um servidor\n");

            scanf("%d",&opc);

        }

        if(opc == 1){

            dhcp++;

              printf("IP\n");

                        scanf("%d",&ip);

                            printf("gateway\n");

                                scanf("%d",&gate);

                                      printf(" DNS\n");

                                          scanf("%d",&dns);

                            printf("-----servidor dhcp ativado-----\n\n");

        }

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você possui um erro de sintaxe em

```
while((resp<1) (resp>2))
```

Se você deseja que as duas condições sejam atendidas então modifique para:

```
while((resp<1) && (resp>2))
```

Se você deseja que no mínimo uma duas condições seja atendida então modifique para:

```
while((resp<1) || (resp>2))
```

o C vai interpretar isso como uma chamada a função (resp<1) do jeito que está atualmente.

A linha 20 é o mesmo erro com a mesma solução proposta.

O seguinte artigo sobre operadores lógicos pode te ajudar: [Operators](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/)

O seguinte artigo sobre controle de fluxo pode te ajudar: [Statements and flow control](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/)

O seguinte arquivo sobre funções pode te ajudar: [Functions](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/)

Comment: vlw, deu certo, ajudou muito